# Read text files line by line and convert to matrix - what is different about these two data files?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a simple function that is supposed to read a text file line by line and produce a matrix of floating point values.  The function is here:

```
testCNVs <- function(infile){
    dataLines <- readLines(infile)                                  # read the input file into a character vector
    nLines  <- length(dataLines)
    splitLines <- strsplit(dataLines," ")                           # create a list with nLines elements
    print(length(splitLines))
    convLines <- sapply(splitLines,function(x) {as.numeric(x)})     # convert the list to numbers with NAs for the blanks
    print(length(convLines))
    numLines  <- sapply(convLines,function(x){x <- na.omit(x)})     # change the NAs to blanks
    print(dim(numLines))    
}
```

The print statements are to monitor the progress. I have two very similar data files (apparently different only in the number of lines in the original file).  My problem is that the function fails with one and not with the other.  The issue seems to be the line in which I convert the elements of a the list created when I split the text line to numeric.  In one case I end up with the desired 18x124 matrix, in the other, I end up with a 1x896 vector. Why would this happen?  Here are the two data files.

file1.txt

```
  0.500     1.2880 156.086758    9.86950 3.0896e+00      6.320      66.19     3.1257    49.7422      0.711       2.75 6.1275e-01    296.875 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  12.487138  3.3310595 0.0000e+00
  1.000     1.2857 156.508435   10.08103 1.7269e+00      6.807      70.28     0.3560    91.6360      1.422       2.75 5.9009e-01    297.703 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  12.747106  2.7307977 0.0000e+00
  1.500     1.2832 156.880561   10.53558 1.0643e+00      7.158      91.16     0.2380    94.2283      2.134       2.75 6.4258e-01    298.439 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.010151  2.0666651 0.0000e+00
  2.000     1.3473 157.824200   11.83085 8.0739e-01      7.693      69.48     0.2094    94.9002      2.845       2.75 6.9486e-01    299.505 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.491949  1.6518261 0.0000e+00
  2.500     1.3106 156.767926   13.73845 4.7804e-01      8.292      48.66     0.1990    95.1468      3.556       2.75 6.4653e-01    297.913 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.858667  1.3208455 0.0000e+00
  3.000     1.3137 156.609606   13.97187 3.1583e-01      8.309      82.53     0.1964    95.2085      4.267       2.75 7.7640e-01    297.578 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.864357  1.3101815 0.0000e+00
  3.500     1.3023 156.574184   13.98951 2.1854e-01      8.309      62.05     0.1993    95.1404      4.978       2.75 7.1006e-01    297.640 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.834689  1.3101343 0.0000e+00
  4.000     1.2916 156.505735   13.99527 2.1464e-01      8.313      61.81     0.1972    95.1882      5.689       2.75 6.8713e-01    297.630 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.833892  1.3101343 0.0000e+00
  4.500     1.2831 156.397509   14.01459 1.4992e-01      8.314      61.59     0.1972    95.1902      6.401       2.75 7.2678e-01    297.522 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.867959  1.3101343 0.0000e+00
  5.000     1.2809 156.426024   13.99879 1.1131e-01      8.314      60.92     0.1986    95.1574      7.112       2.75 6.4776e-01    297.601 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.878778  1.3101343 0.0000e+00
  5.500     1.2798 156.410180   13.99373 1.2153e-01      8.318      60.33     0.1999    95.1251      7.823       2.75 6.5598e-01    297.583 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.870762  1.3010778 0.0000e+00
  6.000     1.2797 156.450556   13.99847 1.1267e-01      8.319      59.97     0.1956    95.2281      8.534       2.75 7.2359e-01    297.661 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.866675  1.2950505 0.0000e+00
  6.500     1.2796 156.412438   13.99934 8.9614e-02      8.322      59.48     0.1966    95.2043      9.245       2.75 6.8709e-01    297.589 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.862621  1.2920288 0.0000e+00
  7.000     1.2804 156.437125   13.99819 8.7322e-02      8.324      58.80     0.1990    95.1478      9.956       2.75 6.9542e-01    297.628 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.857080  1.2905029 0.0000e+00
  7.500     1.2833 156.469905   14.00157 7.2912e-02      8.325      58.30     0.1966    95.2046     10.667       2.75 7.0954e-01    297.656 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.853720  1.2889318 0.0000e+00
  8.000     1.2842 156.485019   14.00458 6.2875e-02      8.328      57.75     0.1965    95.2064     11.379       2.75 6.4335e-01    297.675 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.848955  1.2842325 0.0000e+00
  8.500     1.2804 156.440762   14.01660 6.2007e-02      8.329      57.20     0.1964    95.2086     12.090       2.75 6.7422e-01    297.634 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.849385  1.2836959 0.0000e+00
  9.000     1.2801 156.433763   14.02396 4.9313e-02      8.333      56.60     0.1972    95.1898     12.801       2.75 6.6198e-01    297.624 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.851002  1.2895348 0.0000e+00
  9.500     1.2800 156.459043   14.01182 4.0629e-02      8.334      56.04     0.1956    95.2281     13.512       2.75 6.9924e-01    297.674 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.851038  1.2881041 0.0000e+00
 10.000     1.2797 156.451520   14.00914 2.8121e-02      8.336      55.56     0.1988    95.1516     14.223       2.75 6.9887e-01    297.663 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.851038  1.2821771 0.0000e+00
 10.500     1.2795 156.428611   14.01802 2.3549e-02      8.339      55.00     0.1985    95.1586     14.935       2.75 7.1955e-01    297.622 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.851038  1.2828681 0.0000e+00
 11.000     1.2795 156.464906   14.03034 2.9420e-02      8.341      54.61     0.1974    95.1855     15.646       2.75 6.8163e-01    297.691 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.863084  1.2812546 0.0000e+00
 11.500     1.2796 156.454618   14.03200 2.6834e-02      8.344      54.07     0.2006    95.1081     16.357       2.75 7.0976e-01    297.670 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.863096  1.2808389 0.0000e+00
 12.000     1.2796 156.465874   14.03700 1.6711e-02      8.344      53.42     0.2022    95.0711     17.068       2.75 6.5849e-01    297.691 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.825505  1.2808303 0.0000e+00
 12.500     1.2797 156.397441   14.03301 1.4758e-02      8.346      52.83     0.2000    95.1223     17.779       2.75 7.2257e-01    297.560 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.816238  1.2808303 0.0000e+00
 13.000     1.2797 156.451338   14.03689 7.6591e-03      8.349      52.31     0.1973    95.1877     18.490       2.75 6.7028e-01    297.663 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.821739  1.2813192 0.0000e+00
 13.500     1.2797 156.450731   14.02784 9.6618e-03      8.349      51.83     0.1946    95.2518     19.201       2.75 6.7952e-01    297.661 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.823731  1.2808192 0.0000e+00
 14.000     1.2798 156.454890   14.03276 1.0652e-02      8.349      51.36     0.1939    95.2679     19.913       2.75 6.9713e-01    297.668 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.854319  1.2808303 0.0000e+00
 14.500     1.2799 156.482606   14.03352 7.1330e-03      8.350      50.69     0.1981    95.1681     20.624       2.75 6.2998e-01    297.720 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.882687  1.2808303 0.0000e+00
 15.000     1.2821 156.512646   14.03488 7.3049e-03      8.352      50.20     0.1938    95.2697     21.335       2.75 7.4480e-01    297.751 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.864629  1.2808303 0.0000e+00
 15.500     1.2844 156.456387   14.04326 9.2147e-03      8.354      49.71     0.1979    95.1742     22.046       2.75 7.3726e-01    297.619 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.835951  1.2808303 0.0000e+00
 16.000     1.2855 156.487458   14.04860 5.0632e-03      8.354      49.19     0.1998    95.1274     22.757       2.75 6.6505e-01    297.666 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.835008  1.2808303 0.0000e+00
 16.500     1.2875 156.463825   14.04850 4.0083e-03      8.354      48.70     0.2004    95.1126     23.468       2.75 8.1094e-01    297.598 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.833823  1.2808303 0.0000e+00
 17.000     1.2874 156.504363   14.05799 2.7493e-03      8.355      48.15     0.1983    95.1633     24.180       2.75 6.8746e-01    297.675 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.834267  1.2808303 0.0000e+00
 17.500     1.2878 156.483234   14.05947 2.2657e-03      8.358      47.56     0.1970    95.1940     24.891       2.75 7.9055e-01    297.631 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.827685  1.2872795 0.0000e+00
 18.000     1.2892 156.491727   14.04950 1.0471e-03      8.358      47.08     0.1968    95.2000     25.602       2.75 6.6244e-01    297.631 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.827602  1.2887571 0.0000e+00
 18.500     1.2895 156.477155   14.05513 9.3778e-05      8.359      46.47     0.1986    95.1566     26.313       2.75 7.2391e-01    297.601 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.818660  1.2892603 0.0000e+00
 19.000     1.2891 156.483674   14.05855 1.8960e-06      8.359      45.96     0.2013    95.0912     27.024       2.75 7.2646e-01    297.617 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.816455  1.2879653 0.0000e+00
 19.500     1.2893 156.517385   14.05979 1.0000e-12      8.359      45.39     0.2007    95.1049     27.736       2.75 7.9963e-01    297.679 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.856846  1.2901090 0.0000e+00
 20.000     1.2893 156.463685   14.06713 1.0000e-12      8.359      44.86     0.2003    95.1142     28.447       2.75 7.3202e-01    297.577 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.862869  1.2906072 0.0000e+00
 20.500     1.2893 156.534212   14.06923 5.1451e-05      8.359      44.37     0.2002    95.1169     29.158       2.75 7.6139e-01    297.711 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.842233  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 21.000     1.2889 156.522718   14.05906 -2.322e-06      8.359      43.80     0.1992    95.1416     29.869       2.75 6.7900e-01    297.694 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.830992  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 21.500     1.2887 156.537109   14.05268 1.0000e-12      8.360      43.31     0.2033    95.0438     30.580       2.75 6.4449e-01    297.724 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.830243  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 22.000     1.2890 156.510759   14.05903 1.0000e-12      8.361      42.84     0.2036    95.0373     31.292       2.75 7.3233e-01    297.670 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.828242  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 22.500     1.2887 156.515672   14.05880 1.0000e-12      8.362      42.21     0.2017    95.0817     32.003       2.75 7.4298e-01    297.683 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.825920  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 23.000     1.2888 156.504657   14.05670 1.0000e-12      8.364      41.78     0.2030    95.0521     32.713       2.75 7.0526e-01    297.661 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.821181  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 23.500     1.2884 156.521377   14.06314 1.0000e-12      8.363      41.19     0.2079    94.9363     33.425       2.75 6.8581e-01    297.698 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.821068  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 24.000     1.2878 156.540582   14.05883 1.0000e-12      8.363      40.68     0.2046    95.0127     34.136       2.75 6.7242e-01    297.741 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.819404  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 24.500     1.2874 156.493554   14.05299 1.0000e-12      8.364      40.16     0.2025    95.0636     34.847       2.75 7.3724e-01    297.655 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.820175  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 25.000     1.2871 156.533892   14.05999 1.0000e-12      8.364      39.60     0.2023    95.0699     35.558       2.75 6.4275e-01    297.736 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.890716  1.2901493 0.0000e+00
 25.500     1.2865 156.507871   14.07497 1.0000e-12      8.363      38.97     0.2006    95.1072     36.269       2.75 7.4506e-01    297.693 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.890121  1.2894749 0.0000e+00
 26.000     1.2860 156.465363   14.06954 1.0000e-12      8.364      38.23     0.2024    95.0668     36.981       2.75 7.5792e-01    297.618 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.843668  1.2892453 0.0000e+00
 26.500     1.2867 156.502805   14.06351 1.0000e-12      8.364      37.92     0.2018    95.0811     37.692       2.75 7.7149e-01    297.681 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.838453  1.2901641 0.0000e+00
 27.000     1.2867 156.493359   14.06892 1.0000e-12      8.363      37.49     0.2021    95.0730     38.403       2.75 6.8002e-01    297.662 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.823929  1.2882365 0.0000e+00
 27.500     1.2860 156.526746   14.07005 1.0000e-12      8.363      36.92     0.2072    94.9523     39.114       2.75 6.7018e-01    297.734 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.819674  1.2873219 0.0000e+00
 28.000     1.2864 156.531047   14.06016 1.0000e-12      8.364      36.43     0.2041    95.0251     39.825       2.75 7.1571e-01    297.738 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.824777  1.2884909 0.0000e+00
 28.500     1.2869 156.538596   14.06522 1.0000e-12      8.364      35.88     0.2002    95.1176     40.536       2.75 8.4728e-01    297.747 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.827872  1.2878284 0.0000e+00
 29.000     1.2872 156.520926   14.06976 1.0000e-12      8.364      35.38     0.2033    95.0431     41.248       2.75 8.1434e-01    297.710 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.829205  1.2885061 0.0000e+00
 29.500     1.2878 156.536587   14.06975 1.0000e-12      8.364      34.92     0.1981    95.1695     41.959       2.75 7.1990e-01    297.732 1.7939e+00 1.7939e+00  13.831381  1.2863039 0.0000e+00
 30.000     1.2873 156.494928   14.06140 1.0000e-12      8.364      34.33     0.1996    95.1321     42.670       2.75 7.1967e-01    297.659 1.9776e+00 1.9776e+00  13.830279  1.2887613 0.0000e+00
 30.500     1.2884 156.469808   14.05811 1.0000e-12      8.364      33.82     0.2028    95.0569     43.381       2.75 6.4537e-01    297.598 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.827550  1.2901792 0.0000e+00
 31.000     1.2897 156.506117   14.06009 1.0000e-12      8.364      33.25     0.2069    94.9582     44.092       2.75 7.1627e-01    297.653 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.825473  1.2894481 0.0000e+00
 31.500     1.2912 156.535573   14.06303 1.0000e-12      8.365      32.68     0.2025    95.0642     44.803       2.75 7.1679e-01    297.692 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.820157  1.2901236 0.0000e+00
 32.000     1.2917 156.522457   14.06462 1.0000e-12      8.366      32.25     0.2033    95.0445     45.515       2.75 6.8391e-01    297.661 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.819780  1.2877884 0.0000e+00
 32.500     1.2913 156.528736   14.06832 1.0000e-12      8.368      31.66     0.2030    95.0511     46.226       2.75 7.1501e-01    297.678 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.827102  1.2904721 0.0000e+00
 33.000     1.2917 156.501118   14.07742 1.0000e-12      8.368      31.11     0.2035    95.0386     46.937       2.75 8.6172e-01    297.621 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.827940  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 33.500     1.2911 156.497332   14.08678 1.0000e-12      8.368      30.63     0.2029    95.0555     47.648       2.75 6.9834e-01    297.621 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.835213  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 34.000     1.2925 156.549386   14.07556 1.0000e-12      8.369      30.08     0.2021    95.0737     48.359       2.75 6.6366e-01    297.703 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.835395  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 34.500     1.2921 156.525347   14.06468 1.0000e-12      8.369      29.61     0.2037    95.0349     49.071       2.75 7.4975e-01    297.663 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.823873  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 35.000     1.2924 156.540858   14.06108 1.0000e-12      8.369      29.03     0.2031    95.0478     49.782       2.75 7.1763e-01    297.688 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.819397  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 35.500     1.2913 156.548453   14.06188 1.0000e-12      8.369      28.53     0.2010    95.0992     50.493       2.75 7.5640e-01    297.715 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.814702  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 36.000     1.2921 156.506076   14.06847 1.0000e-12      8.369      27.98     0.2042    95.0219     51.204       2.75 7.1188e-01    297.626 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.811291  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 36.500     1.2914 156.502278   14.07163 1.0000e-12      8.369      27.40     0.2026    95.0610     51.915       2.75 7.3991e-01    297.627 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.815879  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 37.000     1.2912 156.540268   14.07461 1.0000e-12      8.369      26.89     0.2003    95.1145     52.626       2.75 6.8996e-01    297.702 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.822075  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 37.500     1.2913 156.506292   14.06765 1.0000e-12      8.369      26.41     0.2045    95.0165     53.338       2.75 7.5655e-01    297.636 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.823639  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 38.000     1.2911 156.556040   14.06473 1.0000e-12      8.369      25.89     0.2019    95.0776     54.049       2.75 7.5495e-01    297.733 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.832001  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 38.500     1.2911 156.559078   14.06726 1.0000e-12      8.369      25.32     0.2023    95.0683     54.760       2.75 7.2876e-01    297.738 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.833490  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 39.000     1.2918 156.553054   14.06715 1.0000e-12      8.369      24.82     0.2033    95.0448     55.471       2.75 8.2400e-01    297.718 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.865316  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 39.500     1.2925 156.576982   14.07167 1.0000e-12      8.369      24.31     0.2040    95.0266     56.182       2.75 7.3652e-01    297.756 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.866453  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 40.000     1.2911 156.541016   14.07713 1.0000e-12      8.370      23.76     0.2052    94.9995     56.893       2.75 8.3602e-01    297.704 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.839631  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 40.500     1.2910 156.554259   14.07253 1.0000e-12      8.369      23.22     0.2030    95.0501     57.605       2.75 6.8998e-01    297.730 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.838907  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 41.000     1.2912 156.588062   14.06933 1.0000e-12      8.369      22.71     0.2019    95.0769     58.316       2.75 7.8401e-01    297.792 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.823346  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 41.500     1.2910 156.541858   14.06912 1.0000e-12      8.369      22.19     0.2037    95.0353     59.027       2.75 7.3328e-01    297.706 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.819842  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 42.000     1.2911 156.534033   14.06928 1.0000e-12      8.369      21.65     0.2028    95.0558     59.738       2.75 7.6086e-01    297.690 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.836889  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 42.500     1.2915 156.554950   14.06753 1.0000e-12      8.369      15.81     0.2034    95.0418     60.449       2.75 6.9900e-01    297.725 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.846287  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 43.000     1.2912 156.521430   14.06778 1.0000e-12      8.369       6.39     0.2034    95.0430     61.161       2.75 7.2253e-01    297.666 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.832786  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 43.500     1.2911 156.587877   14.07755 1.0000e-12      8.370      11.19     0.2001    95.1201     61.872       2.75 9.0889e-01    297.793 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.817488  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 44.000     1.2914 156.564072   14.07898 1.0000e-12      8.370      19.46     0.2115    94.8492     62.583       2.76 7.3148e-01    297.744 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.815205  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 44.500     1.2905 156.566786   14.06783 1.0000e-12      8.369      18.88     0.2045    95.0148     63.294       2.75 7.2968e-01    297.759 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.807943  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 45.000     1.2905 156.536301   14.06266 1.0000e-12      8.369      18.49     0.2009    95.1018     64.005       2.76 7.3150e-01    297.702 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.807344  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 45.500     1.2921 156.537965   14.06876 1.0000e-12      8.370      17.88     0.2030    95.0505     64.716       2.75 7.1425e-01    297.687 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.803522  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 46.000     1.2925 156.572640   14.06819 1.0000e-12      8.370      17.39     0.2052    94.9980     65.427       2.75 7.2635e-01    297.748 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.802858  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 46.500     1.2936 156.571326   14.07314 1.0000e-12      8.372      16.92     0.2021    95.0717     66.139       2.75 6.9862e-01    297.734 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.796385  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 47.000     1.2941 156.575750   14.05475 1.0000e-12      8.373      16.07     0.2004    95.1135     66.850       2.75 6.8616e-01    297.736 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.796337  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 47.500     1.2925 156.547627   14.05443 1.0000e-12      8.374      15.83     0.2060    94.9805     67.561       2.76 7.4904e-01    297.701 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.831908  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 48.000     1.2924 156.555890   14.06196 1.0000e-12      8.372      15.23     0.2047    95.0097     68.272       2.75 7.1744e-01    297.717 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.839501  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 48.500     1.2924 156.571069   14.05974 1.0000e-12      8.373      14.61     0.2018    95.0800     68.983       2.76 7.6773e-01    297.746 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.832982  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 49.000     1.2931 156.557067   14.06135 1.0000e-12      8.373      14.03     0.2039    95.0291     69.694       2.75 1.0110e+00    297.711 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.830487  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 49.500     1.2939 156.593932   14.07885 1.0000e-12      8.373      13.54     0.2043    95.0195     70.405       2.76 8.5188e-01    297.773 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.823036  1.2905983 0.0000e+00
 50.000     1.2939 156.563903   14.07100 1.0000e-12      8.372      13.05     0.2052    94.9997     71.117       2.76 9.7985e-01    297.715 1.9176e+00 1.9176e+00  13.821139  1.2911076 0.0000e+00
 50.500     1.2946 156.578382   14.05361 1.0000e-12      8.373      12.55     0.2016    95.0850     71.828       2.76 1.0054e+00    297.735 1.9696e+00 1.9696e+00  13.823970  1.2918291 0.0000e+00
 51.000     1.2975 156.556457   14.05649 1.0000e-12      8.374      12.06     0.2025    95.0630     72.539       2.76 7.8206e-01    297.660 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.846863  1.2927341 0.0000e+00
 51.500     1.2979 156.560304   14.06718 1.0000e-12      8.374      11.16     0.2035    95.0400     73.250       2.76 7.8922e-01    297.664 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.840029  1.2961636 0.0000e+00
 52.000     1.2994 156.605435   14.05862 1.0000e-12      8.374      10.84     0.2023    95.0687     73.961       2.75 7.3711e-01    297.732 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.838063  1.2986801 0.0000e+00
 52.500     1.2999 156.592824   14.06901 1.0000e-12      8.374      10.42     0.2006    95.1098     74.673       2.76 7.3425e-01    297.702 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.836162  1.2984049 0.0000e+00
 53.000     1.3016 156.614749   14.06112 1.0000e-12      8.374       9.88     0.2029    95.0559     75.384       2.76 8.7055e-01    297.725 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.794062  1.3004935 0.0000e+00
 53.500     1.3079 156.679704   14.06073 1.0000e-12      8.374       9.37     0.1992    95.1433     76.095       2.76 6.9439e-01    297.777 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.808426  1.3003663 0.0000e+00
 54.000     1.3100 156.662171   14.05951 1.0000e-12      8.374       8.83     0.1989    95.1503     76.806       2.76 6.4038e-01    297.721 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.814745  1.3030058 0.0000e+00
 54.500     1.3088 156.660885   14.03639 1.0000e-12      8.374       8.29     0.2060    94.9805     77.517       2.76 7.0522e-01    297.732 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.783048  1.3112268 0.0000e+00
 55.000     1.3087 156.656797   14.04779 1.0000e-12      8.374       7.79     0.1938    95.2707     78.228       2.76 8.2231e-01    297.724 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.765811  1.3099036 0.0000e+00
 55.500     1.3302 156.827301   14.03756 1.0000e-12      8.374       7.28     0.1958    95.2220     78.940       2.76 7.4481e-01    297.805 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.809924  1.3101407 0.0000e+00
 56.000     1.3443 156.944770   14.04793 1.0000e-12      8.374       6.73     0.1955    95.2291     79.651       2.76 7.5012e-01    297.869 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.820237  1.3101343 0.0000e+00
 56.500     1.3445 156.987871   13.98753 1.0000e-12      8.373       6.22     0.1955    95.2292     80.362       2.76 5.6650e-01    297.948 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.806546  1.3306961 0.0000e+00
 57.000     1.3453 157.014748   13.93833 1.0000e-12      8.369       5.70     0.1892    95.3787     81.073       2.77 4.9951e-01    297.990 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.799743  1.3392199 0.0000e+00
 57.500     1.3485 157.031535   13.93418 1.0000e-12      8.369       5.17     0.1794    95.6153     81.784       2.76 7.3729e-01    297.985 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.750370  1.3390531 0.0000e+00
 58.000     1.3555 157.074010   13.94032 1.0000e-12      8.365       4.64     0.1723    95.7841     82.495       2.76 5.5584e-01    297.988 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.752180  1.3402179 0.0000e+00
 58.500     1.3585 157.120311   13.93214 1.0000e-12      8.364       4.11     0.1631    96.0052     83.206       2.76 4.6453e-01    298.041 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.761278  1.3466655 0.0000e+00
 59.000     1.3605 157.150649   13.91511 1.0000e-12      8.364       3.61     0.1591    96.1003     83.918       2.76 5.5275e-01    298.076 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.746935  1.3506394 0.0000e+00
 59.500     1.3614 157.141966   13.89140 1.0000e-12      8.363       3.06     0.1530    96.2466     84.629       2.76 7.6588e-01    298.050 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.714343  1.3556304 0.0000e+00
 60.000     1.3734 157.258867   13.89220 1.0000e-12      8.361       2.52     0.1465    96.4033     85.340       2.76 4.8079e-01    298.136 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.712852  1.3586726 0.0000e+00
 60.500     1.3756 157.294076   13.87309 1.0000e-12      8.359       1.98     0.1403    96.5537     86.051       2.76 4.0711e-01    298.178 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.695143  1.3665498 0.0000e+00
 61.000     1.3772 157.308323   13.84726 1.0000e-12      8.355       1.45     0.1257    96.9056     86.762       2.76 3.5429e-01    298.186 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.652023  1.3702106 0.0000e+00
 61.500     1.3783 157.318808   13.82996 1.0000e-12      8.354       0.90     0.1178    97.0977     87.474       2.76 3.9017e-01    298.193 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.676965  1.3774574 0.0000e+00
 62.000     1.3765 157.436802   13.84205 1.0000e-12      8.354       0.80     0.1329    96.7289     88.183       2.77 2.5977e-01    298.438 1.9689e+00 1.9689e+00  13.646137  1.3795170 0.0000e+00
```

file2.txt

```
  0.500     5.5061 195.520719   12.35942 3.4177e+01      6.522       7.60     6.3683    20.9581      0.711       8.69 3.1189e+00    320.448 3.0986e+01 3.0986e+01  11.123267  7.4622208 0.0000e+00
  1.000     5.5075 195.790748   12.50109 1.2494e+01      6.869       7.21     3.8923    37.4907      1.422       8.69 3.2963e+00    320.876 3.0435e+01 3.0435e+01  11.115402  7.3447965 0.0000e+00
  1.500     5.5498 195.109027   11.94862 4.9686e+00      7.237       6.53     3.9482    37.2668      2.133       8.69 3.4536e+00    319.316 2.9866e+01 2.9866e+01  11.748403  6.3338864 0.0000e+00
  2.000     5.6606 195.703333   11.72424 3.2092e+00      8.193       5.63     3.8001    38.6686      2.845       8.67 3.9227e+00    319.281 2.5233e+01 2.5233e+01  12.580459  5.3724137 0.0000e+00
  2.500     5.5111 198.262256   12.42491 2.0702e+00      8.065       5.27     3.8844    37.8678      3.556       8.67 3.1441e+00    324.885 2.3592e+01 2.3592e+01  12.440895  5.5491392 0.0000e+00
  3.000     5.5116 198.227707   12.41333 1.1610e+00      8.066       4.95     3.9142    37.5857      4.267       8.67 3.0918e+00    324.826 2.3627e+01 2.3627e+01  12.436287  5.5494505 0.0000e+00
  3.500     5.5122 198.211567   12.41535 7.0104e-01      8.065       4.46     3.8921    37.7936      4.978       8.67 3.1390e+00    324.793 2.3465e+01 2.3465e+01  12.435175  5.5494505 0.0000e+00
  4.000     5.5151 198.205261   12.39944 4.2714e-01      8.066       3.97     3.9059    37.6637      5.689       8.67 3.0511e+00    324.752 2.3355e+01 2.3355e+01  12.445998  5.5403087 0.0000e+00
  4.500     5.5121 198.168590   12.38968 2.3805e-01      8.065       3.45     3.8808    37.9009      6.401       8.67 3.2722e+00    324.724 2.3552e+01 2.3552e+01  12.448357  5.5389280 0.0000e+00
  5.000     5.5128 198.206842   12.41795 1.2105e-01      8.066       2.63     3.8662    38.0396      7.112       8.67 3.8632e+00    324.779 2.2779e+01 2.2779e+01  12.444106  5.5342112 0.0000e+00
  5.500     5.5083 198.192329   12.43165 7.2433e-02      8.066       2.23     3.8465    38.2272      7.823       8.67 3.7356e+00    324.803 2.1756e+01 2.1756e+01  12.430110  5.5395597 0.0000e+00
  6.000     5.5091 198.173107   12.42226 3.1936e-02      8.066       1.73     3.8368    38.3202      8.534       8.67 3.7800e+00    324.763 2.1655e+01 2.1655e+01  12.430048  5.5347954 0.0000e+00
  6.500     5.5089 198.149250   12.43473 7.3908e-03      8.069       1.14     3.8313    38.3728      9.245       8.67 3.9825e+00    324.726 2.1338e+01 2.1338e+01  12.423751  5.5381550 0.0000e+00
  7.000     5.5079 198.671124   12.44895 -3.164e-03      8.063       0.98     3.8316    38.3699      9.958       8.67 4.3604e+00    325.592 2.2043e+01 2.2043e+01  12.418789  5.5409432 0.0000e+00
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not found what it is about these two data files that makes the function fail in one case and not the other, I have found a better way to accomplish the same thing without resorting to the string splitting and subsequent removal of the NAs.  I offer it as an answer to the question in case someone else encounters a similar problem.  The solution requires some additional input information (the size of the output matrix); in my real problem I obtain these values (nrows,ncols) from elsewhere in the data file.  In short, the solution is illustrated in this function:

```
testCNVs2 <- function(infile){
    dataLines <- readLines(infile)
    dataCon   <- textConnection(dataLines)      # Establish a connection
    dataScan  <- scan(dataCon, what=numeric())  # Scan into a vector
    dataMat   <- matrix(dataScan,nrow=nrows, ncol=ncols,byrow=TRUE)
    dataMat
```

This function does not choke on the data files that killed the first version.  Problem solved, if not understood.